# Searching a nested set

Tags: mysql, algorithm, search, nested-sets

I've got a MySQL table that acts like a nested set in order to contain a hierarchy of categories. The table schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `lft` int(11) default NULL,
  `rgt` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_categories_on_parent_id_and_name` (`parent_id`,`name`)
)
```

`lft` and `rgt` define the left and right boundaries of a node (the way a nested set works is that each node's id falls within its parent's boundaries), and `parent_id` specifies the parent node. The unique index allows there to be multiple categories with the same name, as long as they don't have the same parent.

I am trying to figure out a proper way to find a specific node in the set, based on hierarchy. For instance, if I look for foo/bar/baz, I want to retrieve the node named baz, whose parent is named bar, who's parent is named foo. Obviously, I can't just search by name, because there could be multiple categories with the same name.

The way I can think of doing this is to find the topmost category, then find each subsequent category with the given name whose parent id is that of the previously found category, but this doesn't seem very efficient to me. Is there a better way to search a nested set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a perfectly clean and efficient way to do this with nested sets. Storing a list of the node's ancestors in a denormalized column would provide this efficiently, but I don't suggest implementing it.

There is an ok'ish method though, which is 1 query and will conveniently hit the index you already have. You're looking at one join for each level of depth of the target node.

For your example foo-bar-baz

select c3.*
 
from categories c1
inner join categories c2 on c2.parent_id = c1.id AND c2.name = 'bar'
inner join categories c3 on c3.parent_id = c2.id AND c2.name = 'baz'
where c1.name = 'foo'

It's not the greatest, but it's probably your best bet unless you want to go to the effort of storing a bunch of denormalized information. It's fairly straight forward to generate the SQL in code as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
TopVar = 'foo'
MidVar = 'bar'
BotVar = 'baz'

SELECT D0.*
FROM categories D0, categories D1, categories D2
WHERE D0.name = :BotVar
  AND D0.lft > D1.lft
  AND D0.rgt < D1.rgt
  AND D1.name = :MidVar
  AND D1.lft > D2.lft
  AND D1.rgt < D2.rgt
  AND D2.name = :TopVar;
```

-Al.

Comment: Small tip that took me waaaaaaay too long to work out when working with nested sets.

For finding descendents of a node, only refer to the 'lft' column in your query. If you hit left and right columns, your query will contain two range conditions (that is somewhat optimization resistent). If you refer to only left, it'll be a single range condition, which can be fully covered by an index on lft.

Lets say we want the descendants of node A that has left 12 and right 155:

<code>
select *
from categories c
where c.lft between 12 and 155
</code>

Answer (score 0):

i've seen this before in a php project that was handed to me, and ugh, it's just bad..
if you can, break it into at least 2 tables; have at least 1 for categories and 1 for items, so you can join.. either way you're going to need to do multiple queries i'm afraid

Comment: I don't think you quite understood the question; I do have separate tables for categories and items, but I am not concerned about items here. I just want to get the ID of a specific category, based on a given hierarchy.